# SQL long process stats generation for charting best practice

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some SQL Server Store Procs that generates statistical data for charting in a C# web application.

Right now the user in the web app has to wait about 5 minutes to see these charts with updated data and this is a pain in the neck for the user and for me.

Some of the Store procs takes more than 5 minutes to generate the data but the web user don't need to see the info on the fly. Maybe update the chart every 2-3 hours.

So, I dont know what is the best practice to solve this.

I was thinking on creating a windows service that every 2-3 hours will call the SP's and then store the data in different tables.

Any clue on how to deal with this?

Appreciate the help

Comment: Have you identified which queries are having the most performance issues? You could consider using Indexed Views for those queries

Comment: If I recall correctly, you can just create these indexed views and not have to change any of your stored procedures--your query navigator should know to use the indexed view, and you would likely see an increase in performance. This seems like the quickest solution with the least amount of code.

Comment: I have never used Indexed views but sound reasonable!! I will give a try for that. Any link where I can see a good example? Thanks @Scotch

Comment: Indexed views are *a* tool in the box. I think it's a bit premature to suggest that as the solution w/o knowing why the sproc is slow. Indexed views aren't w/o cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, indexed views (kind of like materialized views) can increase performance of certain common queries without having to make temporary tables and things like that.

The benefits of indexed views are **performance** and that it doesn't require much extra coding and effort. When you create an indexed view as opposed to a temp table, the query navigator will (should) know when to take advantage of this view, *without* the end user needing to specify a temp or aggregate table.

Examples of the benefits of indexed views and how to implement them can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

here are some links to indexed views. Like the comments said, views allow you to quickly get information rather then always doing a select every time using a stored proc. Read the second link for a very good explanation about views.

MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms187864%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Very well explained here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199058/SQL-Server-Indexed-Views-Speed-Up-Your-Select-Quer